# Show f is continously differentiable and $f' =g$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let T and T' be regular distributions. T=T$_{f}$ and $T'=T_{g}$ . Assume both f and g are continous. Show that f is continuously differntiable and f'=g.

I define

$\langle T_{f},\Phi \rangle  = $$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\phi(x) dx$

$\langle T_{g},\Phi \rangle  = $$\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\phi(x) dx$

Now i use the derivation rules for Distributions and get from $T'_{f}(\Phi)$

$\langle T'_{f},\Phi \rangle  =-$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\phi'(x) dx=-[f(x)\phi(x)]^{a}_{-a} +$$\int_\mathbb{R} f'(x)\phi(x) dx$

And $-[f(x)\phi(x)]^{a}_{-a} = 0 $   for $supp(\phi) \subset [-a,a]$

Hence

$ $$\int_\mathbb{R} f'(x)\phi(x) dx =$$\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\phi(x) dx$

Then

$ $$\int_\mathbb{R} (f'(x)-g(x))\phi(x) dx =0$ with Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations

implies that $f'(x)-g(x)=0$

so $f'(x)=g(x)$.

This should be correct. **My Question is how i get that f is continuously differentiable so i can use the Lemma? Does this follow immediately from the derivation rules for distributions??**

Comment: $f'=g$ and $g$ is continuous. You  don't need anything else, right?

Comment: If you convinced yourself that $f'=g$, then it is immediate that $f$ is continuously differentiable, since it has a derivative which equals to a continuous function $g$.

Comment: But i only can use Fundamental lemma of calculus of variations  if f $\in C(\Omega)$ with $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: So i have to show it before i get $f' =g$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't do integration by parts when $f$ is not differentiable!
now we have

$$\langle T_{g},\phi' \rangle=\langle T',\phi \rangle  =-\langle T,\phi' \rangle =-\langle T_{f},\phi' \rangle$$ so

$$\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\phi(x) dx=-\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\phi'(x) dx$$ then by substitution 
$$\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\phi(x) dx=-\int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}f(x)  \dfrac{\phi(x+h)-\phi(x)}{h} dx=\int_\mathbb{R} \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\phi(x)  \dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h} dx $$

from this we have

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}=g(x) \quad a.e$$
finely by the continuity of $g$ we deduce that $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f'=g$

Comment: I see that $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}  \dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}=g(x) \quad a.e$$ follows from your integrals. Is this clear or have I mention something from the line before to this line?

Comment: This follows from the integral, because it is true for every test function $\phi$

Comment: ok. Thank you very much for your help. I wasn´t thinking about your way. I only focused on my method and had the problem with differentiablity of f.

Comment: @mathbob you are welcome, thank you also to make me learn something with you :)